# If $X\times Y$ is homotopy equivalent to a finite-dimensional CW Complex, are $X$ and $Y$ as well?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology, classifying-spaces

Is there a space $X$ that is not homotopy equivalent to a finite-dimensional CW complex for which there exists a space $Y$ such that the product space $X\times Y$ is homotopy equivalent to a finite-dimensional CW complex? If so, how might we construct an example?

A first consideration could be where $X$ has infinitely many nontrivial homology groups, in which case $X$ is not homotopy equivalent to a finite-dimensional CW complex. Yet, in this case it follows from the Künneth Formula that no suitable $Y$ exists. Of course, this only rules out spaces with infinitely many nontrivial homology groups.

Another consideration could be where $X$ is an Eilenberg–Maclane space for which $\pi_1(X)$ has non-trivial torsion, in which case $X$ is, again, not homotopy equivalent to a finite-dimensional CW complex. In this case, if $\pi_1(X)$ is abelian then $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $L\times Z$ for some other space Z and an infinite-dimensional lens space $L$, and hence $X$ has infinitely many nontrivial homology groups, which implies, again, that no suitable $Y$ exists. This has led me to wonder if there exists a space $Y$ and a noncommutative group $G$ with non-trivial torsion such that $Y\times K(G,1)$ is homotopy equivalent to a finite-dimensional CW complex, where $ K(G,1)$ denotes an Eilenberg–Maclane space.

Any insight into approaching this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A triviality: Y can be the empty space

Comment: Not exactly what you wanted, but there are pointed CW complexes $X$ that are not finite, but such that $S^1\wedge X$ is finite, for example $BG$ for $G$ an infinite acyclic group.

Comment: If $Y$ is nonempty then $X$ is a homotopy retract of a CW complex, therefore homotopy equivalent to a CW complex. If $X$ is a homotopy retract of a finite-dimensional CW complex, then $X$ has no cohomology above some dimension $d$, for any coefficient system. This in turn implies (if $d\ge 3$) that $X$ is weakly, therefore strongly equivalent, to a $d$-dimensional complex.

Comment: Just to add references to Tom's  answer. The last sentence it is  theorem E (p.63) of C.T.C. Wal, "Finiteness conditions for CW complexes", see  http://math.uchicago.edu/~shmuel/tom-readings/wall%20finiteness%201.pdf. The statement that a homotopy retract of a CW-complex is a CW complex is e.g. in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology", proposition A.11.

Comment: A postscript to Igor Belegradek's comment:  The argument in Proposition A.11 of my book shows that a space dominated by a CW complex of dimension $n$ is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex of dimension $n+1$, where the extra dimension arises from a mapping telescope construction.  The argument, which is due to J.H.C.Whitehead if I remember correctly, uses only elementary homotopy theory.  Using cohomology and Wall's work one obtains the stronger result that the increase in dimension is not really necessary, at least in dimensions 3 and greater.

Comment: There are examples by R. Bing and many other mathematicians when a product of a non-manifold B and a real line gives a euclidean space, see e.g. the following papers and references there:
https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1958-64-03/S0002-9904-1958-10160-3/S0002-9904-1958-10160-3.pdf
https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-01/S0002-9939-1961-0123303-2/S0002-9939-1961-0123303-2.pdf
However, I do not know whether such space B has the homotopy type of a CW-complex.